# Spring Boot 3.2+ with ASM issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, migration

When I migrating spring Boot 3.1+ to 3.2+ I'm getting below exception while compiling my application

Exception:

[ERROR] Could not parse class file VirtualThreadDelegate.class
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Hashing for Java 21 and beyond is not supported yet
at com.sonatype.insight.scan.hash.internal.asm.AsmClassFactory.newClassNode (AsmClassFactory.java:44)
at com.sonatype.insight.scan.hash.internal.JavaDigester.digest (JavaDigester.java:90)
at com.sonatype.insight.scan.hash.internal.DefaultDigester.digest (DefaultDigester.java:75)
at com.sonatype.insight.scan.hash.internal.DefaultDigester.digest (DefaultDigester.java:54)
at com.sonatype.insight.scan.file.ScanUtils.setHash (ScanUtils.java:79)
at com.sonatype.insight.scan.file.FileVisitor.setScanItemHash (FileVisitor.java:552)
at com.sonatype.insight.scan.file.FileVisitor.visitFile (FileVisitor.java:278)
at com.sonatype.insight.scan.file.FileWalker.doWalk (FileWalker.java:86)
at com.sonatype.insight.scan.file.FileWalker.doWalk (FileWalker.java:75)
at com.sonatype.insight.scan.file.FileWalker.doWalk (FileWalker.java:75)

I tried with excluding the older ESM and added a new esm verions 9.6. But it not resolved. Could anyone help me for this issue..

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring, you are using a plugin in sonar that is too old.